# R: Usage of greek letters within captions in ggtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtitle

I have a problem that I am not able to solve at the moment. I want to use greek letters in my plot titles. I can make:

```
ggtitle("My title")
```

And I know how to print an alpha.

```
ggtitle(bquote(alpha))
```

But how it is possible to combine these two in the caption "My title for α"?

Thank you for your help!

Michael

edit: some tagged this as duplicate, but the suggested answers do not answers my question if my intention is possible by the usage of ggtitle

Comment: Re duplicate tag - it really doesn't matter how you intend to use the expression, the solution is the same

Comment: Did you try `ggtitle(expression("My title for "~alpha))`. That's basically what the duplicate says.

Comment: ggtitle("My Caption for " * alpha ~ "= 1/2")